# how can i restrict the default Read access for the newly created content(page) for the old groups?

Tags: aem

How can i restrict the default Read access for the newly created content(page) for the old groups?
I have observed that there is a default read access is created for the newly created content(webpage) for the existing all groups.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior. But one correction, the read access is not created for the newly created content, instead it is inherited from the parent.

We have **local policies** and **effective policies**, where the local policies are the one's that are configured for the specific node and the effective policies are those that are inherited from the parent.

Hence, the ACL's of the parent node is effectively applied to the child nodes, unless and until they are denied explicitly for that particular child.

In your case, the parent node would have read access to the old groups, due to which they are applied to the newly created child as well. In case, the old groups are denied read access to the parent, then they will not have read access for the newly created child pages by default.